# my script is running twice each time I call it after installing it using a custom setup.py file

Tags: python, command-line, setuptools

I'm building a command-line script that uses command args. after I did the setup using the setuptools and this setup file

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='notes',
      version='0.1',
      description='A program used to manage your notes and organize them across your machine.',
      url='info',
      author='info',
      author_email='info',
      license='MIT',
      install_requires=[
          'tabulate',
          'argparse'
      ],
      packages=['.'],
      data_files=["config.json"],
      scripts=[],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [ 
        'notes = notes:main' 
    ] 
}
)
```

it runs twice each time I call it from the cmd!!
notes.main function is just a simple one

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False, description= " notes management system", usage=help_msg)

    p.add_argument("command")
    p.add_argument("name")
    p.add_argument("--newname")
    p.add_argument("--tag", action="store")
    p.add_argument("--newtag", action="store")
    p.add_argument("--bytag",  action="store_true")
    p.add_argument("--bydate",  action="store_true")
    p.add_argument("--byname",  action="store_true")


    arg_handeler(sys.argv, p)
```

any idea why? I use python 3.7.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's SOLVED
It appears that I was calling main in the entry file and at the same file the setup file was calling it. so I removed the main function call and it's working just fine!